# Passing value from Parent to Child in PHP

Tags: php

This is my Parent.php Window.........

```
<html>
<body>      
      <form name="parentForm"><input name="toppings" value="" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here " onClick=window.open("toppings.php","popup","width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,");>Search</a></form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Child.php Window........

```
<?php
include("config.php");

//---------------------------------------------

$department = $_GET['department'];
$headoffice = $_GET['headoffice'];
$office = $_GET['office'];
$designation = $_GET['designation'];


if(!empty($department))
{
  if(!empty($headoffice))
  {
    if(!empty($office))
    {
      if(!empty($designation))
      {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE designation='$designation'";
      }
      else
      {         
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE office='$office'";
      } 
    }
    else
    {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE headoffice='$headoffice'";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE department='$department'";
  }
}
else
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
}


$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function updateParent() {    
    s = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
          chk = eval("self.document.childForm.t" + i);
          if (chk.checked)
                s += chk.value + ", ";
    }
    window.opener.document.parentForm.toppings.value = s;

    self.close();
    return false;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

      <form name="childForm" action="">
            <p>Choose topping(s):
                 <table>
                 <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr><td>                 
                  <input type="checkbox" name="t0" value="<?php echo $rows['userid']; ?>" /></td><td><?php echo $rows['userid']; ?></td></tr>
                  <?php }?>

                  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="updateParent();"/></td></tr></table>

      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It not work properely. Child windows checkbox value don't pass in parent window and don't close it self. Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: You have to either submit that form to your child window or use a link with query string values. Currently you are just calling the page name in a link; that doesn't transfer anything.

Comment: what is the connection between your html file and php?

Answer (score 0):

To receive the value in child.php you've to submit the form. Checkout code below:

**parent.php**

```
<form name="parentForm" action="child.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="department" />
    <input type="text" name="headoffice" />
    <input type="text" name="office" />
    <input type="text" name="designation" />
</form>
```

**child.php**

```
...
...
$department = $_GET['department'];
$headoffice = $_GET['headoffice'];
$office = $_GET['office'];
$designation = $_GET['designation'];
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try session. I'm not sure if those method either "post" and "get" will pass all values to the popup window. (correct me if i'm wrong)

**parent.php**

```
session_start();//at very top of the page
$_SESSION['department']; = $_GET['department'];
$_SESSION['headoffice']; = $_GET['headoffice'];
$_SESSION['office']; = $_GET['office'];
$_SESSION['designation']; = $_GET['designation'];
```

**child.php**

```
session_start();//at very top of the page
$department=$_SESSION['department'];
$headoffice=$_SESSION['headoffice'];
$office=$_SESSION['office'];
$designation=$_SESSION['designation'];
```